# visual basic export to png

Tags: excel, vba, charts, export

I am trying to export an excel chart as a png. The chart is constructed by a macro and has a  title defined as

```
.ChartTitle.Text = Area" + NR
```

Where NR is defined as

```
 NR = Str(Cells(2, 2)).
```

This is the code I would like to use:

```
Charts(ChartName).Activate
With ActiveChart
ActiveChart.Export "D:\My_Charts\ChartName.png"
End With
```

I have found multiple other ways to export a chart to a png, the problem is I do not know how to do it for a ChartTitle that is not just plain text, but also contains a variable. How do I fill in the Chart Name and what is the difference with a Chart Title?

I want the output png to be Area_NR.png or AreaNR.png

Apologies in advance if my question is too vague, I am new to using VBA and am trying to work things out, but answers I found on other forums are difficult for me to understand.

Comment: what's `NR`? is that a variable? try `"D:\My_Charts\ChartName" & NR & ".png"`

Answer (score 0):

This is how to get the chart by its name. The *ChartObject* is member of sheet so the sheet needs to be specified. The *VariableName* here is the name of the chart.

```
Dim MyChart As ChartObject

VariableName = "Chart 1"
Set MyChart = Sheets("SheetName").ChartObjects(VariableName)
MyChart.Export "D:\My_Charts\ChartName.png"
```

To get the chart by its title you need to loop through the *ChartObjects* of the sheet and ask for the title.

```
Dim MyChart As ChartObject

VariableTitle = "Chart Title"

For Each MyChart In Sheets("SheetName").ChartObjects
    If MyChart.Chart.ChartTitle.Caption = VariableTitle Then
        MyChart.Export "D:\My_Charts\ChartName.png"
    End If
Next
```